# Nexus access denied with maven encryption enabled

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository, nexus

I just added maven encryption in my project, so all the passwords in my settings.xml file are encrypted. When I try to contact my nexus server by doing a

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

then all dependencies get downloaded properly and the build succeeds. However, when I run the tests as well by just performing a

```
mvn clean install
```

then when the test phase starts and maven tries to contact nexus in order to get testing related dependencies it seems like the access to nexus gets denied, as if the surefire:test plugin goal ignores the maven encryption and tries to connect to nexus with the wrong password.

A sample exception is :

```
-------------------------------------------------------

T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.activity.dashboard.DashboardActivityTest
Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectr
ic-0.pom from repository nexus at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7222/nexus/content/groups/public
Access denied to: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7222/nexus/content/groups/public/org/robolectric/a
ndroid-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:pom:4.3_r2-robolectric-0' fr
om repository nexus (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7222/nexus/content/groups/public): Authorizatio
n failed: Access denied to: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7222/nexus/content/groups/public/org/rob
olectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.pom
```

Edit:

settings.xml looks like this:

```
<settings>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <username>maven</username>
            <password>{encryptedpassword}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7222/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <repositories>
                <!--Overriding the central repo to allow snapshots.-->
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <!--Url will eventually get overridden by the mirror url.-->
                    <url>fake url</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Also, my parent pom.xml contains the distribution management part that may be related:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Nexus Follower Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7222/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Uploading and downloading the snapshots works just fine.

Comment: We are using the same setup here at work, and we have no such problem. Are you sure you've diagnosed the problem correctly? Can we see your settings file (suitably redacted, of course)?

Comment: Not quite sure. The thing is that as soon as I change my password on settings.xml to the unencrypted password then everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, after giving encryption another shot today, it just worked without any exceptions. Not sure what could have caused this, maybe something cached in Intellij, or even a maven/nexus version.